# What version of the compiler does Blue Prism use?

Tags: blueprism

everyone.

Does anybody knows which version of the compiler does Blue Prism (v.6.1) use for code stages? I write in C# and some features of the language are not supported.
I would like to clarify this item in order to understand the possibilities of Blue Prism.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure if you click help/tools in the menu and select about you will get a display window that tells you what version of the .NET framework blueprism is utilising. It also tells you blueprism version, application modeller version as well.

Comment: You was right. In About window it shows Microsoft .Net Framework version (4.7 in my case). But some syntax features of 4.7 doesn't work in code stages(((

Answer (score 1):

I found the [following method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duTt1.png), but I'm not sure that this is exactly what is needed.

---

UPD:
According to [Blue Prism help](https://help.blueprism.com/1137521052)

Blue Prism v5 uses .NET Framework 4.
Blue Prism v6.x uses .NET Framework 4.7, and is designed to use this particular version. Blue Prism v4.2 is based upon .NET Framework 2.0, but will work with later versions which incorporate .NET 2.0.

Comment: I see the same version in my environment.

Comment: I found answer on Blue Prism help

Answer (score 1):

I jsut received an unhandled exception in blueprism and saw a details stack with version of Assemblies. the version that I see is the same that Aleksandr found using code stage.

[image]

Comment: I think Win32 Version is the answer.